# Makefile that calls other makefiles always out of date

Tags: makefile

I've gone over a number of other posts about recursive makefiles. Either I'm doing something wrong or there's a missing feature that I want. With a typical makefile I can check to see if it's out of date with `-q`, for example:

```
make -q || echo "out of date"
```

However, setting up a mechanism to force make to process dependent makefiles causes the root makefile to always be out of date. Here's a working example:

```
#./Makefile
all: myfile

myfile: dir
    cp dir/myfile .

.PHONY: dir
dir:
    $(MAKE) -C dir/

#./dir/Makefile
all: myfile

myfile:
    touch myfile

#testing...
>>> make
make -C dir/
make[1]: Entering directory `dir'
touch myfile
make[1]: Leaving directory `dir'
cp dir/myfile .
>>> make
make -C dir/
make[1]: Entering directory `dir'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `dir'
cp dir/myfile . #<-- this shouldn't be necessary
>>> make -q || echo "out of date"
make -C dir/
out of date
```

Is there a mechanism that allows the recursive make call to return and say "actually everything's up to date here, no need to continue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dacav gave me the idea of calling make explicitly. Though without using a temporary files, target dependencies can be set dynamically using a shell-populated variable. I'm not sure the following is a good solution because even when calling `make` without `-q` it recursively calls `make -q` to populate `OLD_CHILDREN`. Moreover this will happen again unnecessarily for the child makefiles too (assuming multiple levels of recursion).

```
#./Makefile    
CHILDREN=dir/
OLD_CHILDREN=$(foreach c, $(CHILDREN), $(shell make -q -C $(c) || echo $(c)))

all: myfile

myfile: $(OLD_CHILDREN)
    cp dir/myfile .

.PHONY: $(CHILDREN)
$(CHILDREN):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Testing...

```
>>> make -q || echo out of date
make -C dir/
make: *** [dir/] Error 1 #huh??? whatever. still works, returning out of date
out of date
>>> make
make -C dir/
make[1]: Entering directory `dir'
touch myfile
make[1]: Leaving directory `dir'
cp dir/myfile .
>>> make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>>> make -q || echo out of date
>>> #nothing. success :D
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an hacky way of doing it, maybe.
You could invoke `$(MAKE) -q ... && touch something` from inside the makefile, and have the `something` file as requisite for some rule in the outer makefile.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that.  A recursive invocation of make is just another command that make invokes in a shell: the only result of that command available to make is the exit code.  If we could always be sure that the command invoked was a make command, and that we were using the `-q` flag, then we could assume that if it exited with a 0 then nothing was done.  But make does not assume those things.

You will need to rewrite your makefiles to be non-recursive to get the behavior you want.